# Stationarity tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stationarity, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller

It is generally accepted that ADF is the most common test to check whether a time series has a trend or not. My question is:

What if we just regressed the values of the dependend variable on their respective time spots (*Y=a+bt+e)* and we obtained a low signifance level of the "b" coefficient? Would it not be a sufficient evidence of the particular time series' stationarity?

Comment: Mind the difference between deterministic and stochastic trends. The former are deterministic functions of time while the latter are cumulative sums of stationary increments. ADF examines the presence or absence of a stochastic trend (unit root) while your regression does that for a deterministic trend.

Comment: Thank you for making things clear Richard. Your comment though arises another inquiry of mine: If the first, second etc. diferrences or transformations  are meant to eliminate the stochastic trend of the time series, is there any way to do so for the deterministic trend?

Comment: Subtract the trend itself, i.e. subtract the deterministic function of time. In your example that means subtract $bt$.